# How To parse timeString with different Locales?

Tags: javascript, datetime, locale

I want to split a time string in an with hours minutes and ampm seperately.

When I tried it for English time strung with below code :

```
var time = "3:20 PM"; 
var patternParsed = time.replace(new RegExp("(\\W", "g")," ").split(" ");
```

o/p for patternParsed is 3,20,PM

but similar i want to do for korean time string

When I try the above regular expression for korean time string it does not works

```
var koreanTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('ko-KR');
document.writeln("\nKoreanTime  : "+koreanTime);
var patternParsed = koreanTime.replace(new RegExp("(\\W", "g")," ").split(" ");
document.writeln("\nparsed pattern : "+patternParsed);
```

Can someone please help me with this hiw can I split timeString of different locales?

Answer (score 0):

To get a standardized output of `hours,minutes,[AM|PM]` considering the locale adds an unnecessary complexity, it you already have the Date object, you can use it to generate the value:

```js
    var time = new Date();
    if (time.getHours() < 12) {
     var patternParsed = time.getHours() + "," + time.getMinutes() + ",AM";
    } else {
     var patternParsed = (time.getHours() - 12) + "," + time.getMinutes() + ",PM";
    }
    var koreanTime = time.toLocaleTimeString('ko-KR');
    document.writeln("\nKoreanTime : " + koreanTime + "\nparsed pattern : " + patternParsed);
```